# My RegEx won't allow spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regular expression:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9()]+$
```

this doesn't allow spaces, commas, fullstops, forward slashes or backslashes

I am a massive amateur when it comes to this. Can anyone just tell me how to get it to allow spaces?

Comment: Relevant info if learning: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add a space?

```
^[A-Za-z0-9() ]+$
```

Update for comments:

Sample code:

```
        Regex re = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z0-9() \\/.-]+$");
        var result = re.Match(@"a. z-1\2/");
        Console.WriteLine(result.Success);
```

and gives `true`

Comment: @user1016253 - Really? Works for me. Can you add some code etc that you are trying?

Answer (score 5):

You can match whitespace with `\s`:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9()\s]+$
```

Comment: That's alot more than a space.

Comment: \s is not just space, but whitespace ( space, tabs, linebreaks)

Comment: @user1016253: In that case mnojlds's answer should be the correct one, it works for me when trying to match a single space character